# Flutter gradle compilation fails

Tags: flutter, gradle

I have some trouble compiling my Flutter App with Gradle since I updated Flutter.

Here is my setup :

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.18363.1198], locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.2.2 at C:\Users\barba\Documents\flutter
    • Framework revision d79295af24 (2 days ago), 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
    • Dart version 2.13.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\barba\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
```

This is the log I get when trying to compile it.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on HD1900 in debug mode...
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: C:/Users/barba/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.

[...]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audioplayers:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried deleting .gradle from my Android folder, and using `gradlew clean`.
This is what I get :

```
> Configure project :audio_session
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
11 actionable tasks: 11 up-to-date
```

However I did check my *gradle.properties*, there is no `android.enableR8=true`. This string doesn't exist in my whole project folder, there is no way to delete it from the gradle properties.

Any idea on how to solve this issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this type of issue comes from outdated/incompatible package versions. Try this :

1. run `flutter clean`
2. run `flutter pub outdated` to see what versions you can upgrade to
3. update your pubspec.yaml accordingly

If this doesn't work, try ruling out packages one by one until you find the one causing the issue.